# How to save users data on last action?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to hide view in a game, but only in the last level

code:

```
-(IBAction)btContinueClick:(id)sender
{
    if(nCurrentLevel == [first_wordlist count])
    {

        UIAlertView *info = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Well done" message:@"You've completed this game!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [info show]; //// Change Game End Message

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
        [savedStock setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[first_wordlist count]-1] forKey:@"currentlevel"];
        [savedStock writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

If I dont save (hidden matchview) his her data they'll be able to make more and more coins to infinity!

Extra variables :

```
NSMutableArray *firstword;
NSMutableArray *firstjumbledword;
NSMutableArray *first_1st_WordCount;

int nCurrentWord;

IBOutlet UIView *MatchView;

NSMutableArray *firstMatchedWord;
NSMutableArray *firstWordToMatch;
NSMutableArray *firstImageHidden;

NSString *stringResult;

int nCurrentLevel;
int nCurrentLevelPoint;
```

Comment: Welcome to the community, What's the actual problem?

Comment: The actual problem is that I need the last level to end the game! otherwise the user will be able to make infinite amounts of coins, And I'm selling coins to them thus they would feel fooled once finished!

Comment: As suggested by the [SergiusGee's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23217589/468724) you can persist your values in local storage (NSUserDefaults)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others you can always persist your level data locally using NSUserDefaults.

**To Write an Integer:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:2456 forKey:@"Score Level 1"];
```

**To Read the value back from NSUserDefaults:**

```
  NSInteger savedScore= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"Score Level 1"];
```